Getting Telescope Error cannot run config "telescope.nvim" in Lazy vim
Keeps showing the error Failed to run config for telescope.nvim on mac os
Tried to run make in the native directory and still faced the same issue.
Tried deleting the telescope-fzf-native.nvim file , didn't work
the directory for telescope files

~/{user}/.local/share/nvim/lazy/telescope-fzf-native.nvim
~/{user}/.local/share/nvim/lazy/telescope.nvim

During first run it does already contain the build directory inside the telescope-fzf-native.nvim  but it still had this error when I tried to
:Lazy reload telescope.nvim
Failed to run `config` for telescope.nvim

{user}/.config/nvim/lua/sethy/plugins/telescope.lua:20: attempt to index global 'custom_actions' (a nil value)

# stacktrace:
  - lua/sethy/plugins/telescope.lua:20 _in_ **config**


This is the telescope.lua file I ran and got this error
the directory for the file
lua/sethy/plugins/telescope.lua
return {
  "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
  branch = "0.1.x",
  dependencies = {
    "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
    { "nvim-telescope/telescope-fzf-native.nvim", build = "make" },
    "nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons",
    
  },
  config = function()
    local telescope = require("telescope")
    local actions = require("telescope.actions")

  telescope.setup({
      defaults = {
        path_display = { "smart" },
        mappings = {
          i = {
            ["<C-k>"] = actions.move_selection_previous, -- move to prev result
            ["<C-j>"] = actions.move_selection_next, -- move to next result
            ["<C-q>"] = actions.send_selected_to_qflist + custom_actions.open_trouble_qflist,
            
          },
        },
      },
    })

    telescope.load_extension("fzf")

    -- set keymaps
    local keymap = vim.keymap 

    keymap.set("n", "<leader>ff", "<cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>", { desc = "Fuzzy find files in     cwd" })
    keymap.set("n", "<leader>fr", "<cmd>Telescope oldfiles<cr>", { desc = "Fuzzy find recent files" })
    keymap.set("n", "<leader>fs", "<cmd>Telescope live_grep<cr>", { desc = "Find string in cwd" })
    keymap.set("n", "<leader>fc", "<cmd>Telescope grep_string<cr>", { desc = "Find string under cursor in cwd" })
    
  end,
}






This is the health check
telescope: require("telescope.health") .check()
Checking for required plugins

- OK plenary installed.
- WARNING nvim-treesitter not found.

Checking external dependencies

 - 0K rg: found ripgrep 14.1.0
 - WARNING fd: not found. Install [sharkdp/fdl(https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) for extended capabilities
ニニニニ Installed extensions ニニニニニ


Also tried to run without build = "make", deleted the file and re do it also didn't work
I tried with run = "make" then later on    force build it in
:Lazy with gb also didn't work.
Tried in command    shell to    make into
lazy/telescope-fzf-native.nvim directory in    the    terminal
didn't work

All these seem to add a build directory to the file which was suppose to solve this issue from other posts Iv'e seen but doesn't seem to make any difference so Im thinking the issue may be from somewhere else where I can't see.
Anyone has any idea what went wrong

 ["<C-q>"] = actions.send_selected_to_qflist + custom_actions.open_trouble_qflist,

Seems like the problem comes from there...
Try deleting that line and see if it works

Nothing looks with the you lua plugin file. Perhaps the problem with the nvim-telescope not being able to correctly index its dependent fzf-native package.
Most probably the Lazy's cache is also corrupted.
Try commenting out the contents of your telescope.lua file
return {
--[[
    "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim"
    ....
    ....
    end ]]--
}

This will un-index the telescope and its dependent packages. And Lazy would flag them for Clean(X). Remove these packages by pressing X on the :Lazy home screen window.
Once removed, go back to the telescope.lua file and remove the uncomment the commented code. And finally, restart the nvim.
This would reinstall the packages with the correct dependency tree, and if that is the issue, it will be resolved.
